# How to add cards in grid with ant design using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, components, antd

What is ant design?
A design system with values of Nature and Determinacy for better user experience of enterprise applications Read More >> https://ant.design/

A card can be used to display content related to a single subject. The content can consist of multiple elements of varying types and sizes. if you need to add card in grid system try this

Here I'm using 3 Grid in row (you can change on your requirement).

**CODE:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, Icon, Avatar } from 'antd';
const { Meta } = Card;
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';

class Surveys extends React.Component{

  render() {
      return (
      <Row gutter={16}>
        <Col className="gutter-row" span={8}>
        <Card
          cover={<img alt="example" src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/JiqGstEfoWAOHiTxclqi.png" />}
          actions={[<Icon type="setting" />, <Icon type="edit" />, <Icon type="ellipsis" />]}
        >
          <Meta
            avatar={<Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />}
            title="Card title"
            description="This is the description"
          />
        </Card>
        </Col>

        <Col className="gutter-row" span={8}>
        <Card
          cover={<img alt="example" src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/JiqGstEfoWAOHiTxclqi.png" />}
          actions={[<Icon type="setting" />, <Icon type="edit" />, <Icon type="ellipsis" />]}
        >
          <Meta
            avatar={<Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />}
            title="Card title"
            description="This is the description"
          />
        </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col className="gutter-row" span={8}>
        <Card
          cover={<img alt="example" src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/JiqGstEfoWAOHiTxclqi.png" />}
          actions={[<Icon type="setting" />, <Icon type="edit" />, <Icon type="ellipsis" />]}
        >
          <Meta
            avatar={<Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />}
            title="Card title"
            description="This is the description"
          />
        </Card>
        </Col>
        </Row>
  );
  }
}

export default Surveys;
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: And what is your issue?

Comment: issue resolved with question for those who facing :)

Comment: It's Ok to ask and answer your own question, but please do it in the question/answer format of the site rather than putting an answer in the question.

Comment: okay, DavidW,  thank

Comment: how to make like that if the data is from api? what I really meant is how to `array.map` with cards in ant design?